# 3D mathematical vector class

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I've been working on a 3D mathematical vector class which should be as streamlined as possible for use in numerical simulations. It will be used to model 3D-physical vectors.

Here, 3D-vector should be taken in mathematical sense, meaning a tuple (a,b,c).

I hoped to design it in a modern and fast way - but one is never perfect. So, I would be interested in some input from your side.  Any tips for making this faster?

```
//threevector.h
#ifndef threevector_h_
#define threevector_h_

#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>


template <class T>
class threevector
{
private:
  static const int dim = 3; //dimension of vector
  std::array<T,dim> container;  

public:

  //constructors and assignment
  threevector(const double a = 0, const double b = 0, const double c = 0):
  container({{a,b,c}}) {}; //standard constructor
  threevector(const threevector& a): container(a.container) {}; 
  //copy constructor

// add once gcc 4.7 is used
//   threevector(threevector&& other): threevector() {swap(*this, other);} 
  // move constructor

  threevector& operator=(threevector rhs) //assignment
  {
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
  }

  void swap(threevector& first, threevector& second) 
  {first.container.swap(second.container);}


  //operators
  threevector& operator+=(const threevector& rhs) 
  {
    container[0] += rhs.container[0];
    container[1] += rhs.container[1];
    container[2] += rhs.container[2];
    return *this;
  }

  threevector& operator-=(const threevector& rhs) 
  {
    *this += -rhs;
    return *this;
  }

  threevector& operator*=(const double rhs) //scalar multiplication assignment
  {
    container[0] *= rhs;
    container[1] *= rhs;
    container[2] *= rhs;
    return *this;
  }

  threevector& operator/=(const double rhs) //scalar division assignment
  {
    *this *= 1./rhs;
    return *this;
  }


  threevector operator+() const //unary plus
  {
    threevector a(*this);
    return a;
  }

  threevector operator-() const //unary minus
  {
    threevector a(*this);
    a *= -1;
    return a;
  }

  T& operator[](const int input) {return container[input];} //access operator

  const T& operator[](const int input) const {return container[input];} 
  // const access operator

  //utility functions
  double abs() const 
  {return sqrt(container[0]*container[0]+container[1]*container[1]+
   container[2]*container[2]);}
  double abs_sq() const {return pow(abs(),2);}
  void reset() { container[0] = 0; container[1] = 0; container[2] = 0;}
};

//output operator
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const threevector<T>& obj)
{
  os << std::fixed << "(" << obj[0] << "," << obj[1] << "," << obj[2] << ")";
  return os;
}

//addition operator
template<class T>
inline threevector<T> operator+(threevector<T> lhs, const threevector<T>& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}

//subtraction operator
template<class T>
inline threevector<T> operator-(threevector<T> lhs, const threevector<T>& rhs)
{
  lhs -= rhs;
  return lhs;
}

//scalar product
template<class T>
inline double operator*(const threevector<T>& lhs, const threevector<T>& rhs) 
{return lhs[0] * rhs[0] + lhs[1] * rhs[1] + lhs[2] * rhs[2];}


//product with scalar
template<class T>
inline threevector<T> operator*(const double lhs, threevector<T> rhs) 
{
  rhs[0] *= lhs;
  rhs[1] *= lhs;
  rhs[2] *= lhs; 
  return rhs;
}

//product with scalar
template<class T>
inline threevector<T> operator*(threevector<T> lhs, const double rhs){return rhs*lhs;}

// scalar division
template<class T>
inline threevector<T> operator/(threevector<T> lhs, const double rhs){return lhs*(1./rhs);};


#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your design is a little bit confusing. You define your class as a template class, but just about everything takes and returns a `double`. Generally, you should try and be consistent: will this class work for any numeric-like `T`? Then make sure it has constructors that take a `T` instead of a `double`:

```
threevector(T a = T(), T b = T(), T c = T())
```

Similarly for the overloaded operators that multiply/divide by a scalar, and so on.

The name `threevector` is awkward. At the least it should be `three_vector`, but that's still a little awkward. `vector_3d` is more of the "standard" name for this kind of thing.

Your include guards should generally be in all-caps. This is because they are global in scope, and you want to do as much as possible to minimize the possibility of potential name clashes.

```
#ifndef threevector_h_ // should be THREE_VECTOR_H_
#define threevector_h_ // or VECTOR_3D_H_
```

You have some semi-colons where they aren't needed:

```
threevector(const double a = 0, const double b = 0, const double c = 0):
container({{a,b,c}}) {}; //standard constructor
threevector(const threevector& a): container(a.container) {}; // <--- Not needed
```

Comments like `//standard constructor` are obvious and don't really need to be there. Further, your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are redundant; the compiler generated ones are sufficient.

It's often easiest to write `operator+` (and `-`, `*` etc) in terms of `operator+=`:

```
vector_3d operator+(const vector_3d& a, const vector_3d& b)
{
     vector_3d result(a);
     result += b;
     return result;
}
```

For something this simple, it's unlikely you'll be able to speed it up much. The only potential that I can see is replacing the call to `pow()` in:

```
double abs_sq() const {return pow(abs(),2);}
```

with something like:

```
T abs_sq() const
{
    const T ab = abs();  // abs() should also return a T
    return ab * ab;
}
```

which avoids the overhead of a function call to `pow`. In practice, this is unlikely to make much of a difference, however.

Comment: "Further, your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are redundant; the compiler generated ones are sufficient."
Are you sure that the compiler knows about copy-and-swap?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't need to. You only really need to use copy-and-swap with a resource managing class. Your class doesn't manage any resources (that is, anything that is directly `new`ed), hence copy-and-swap is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

- Many of these comments are pointless.  They should only be needed if something is not obvious and needs explanation.  There's no need for individual comments for each constructor and operator; these are already noticeable to those familiar with C++.
- There's no need for `inline` here.  Code in headers are automatically `inline`, so this would apply to all the code here.  Having it here anyway wouldn't cause a problem as the compiler could just remove it, but I'd remove them anyway.
- `dim` could just be renamed to `dimensions`, so that you won't need a comment for it:

  ```
  static const int dimensions = 3;
  ```
- This is not too readable:

  ```
  void swap(threevector& first, threevector& second) 
  {first.container.swap(second.container);}
  ```

  This would also reduce maintainability, especially if additional lines will need to be added.  Using your existing curly brace style, you'll have this:

  ```
  void swap(threevector& first, threevector& second) 
  {
      first.container.swap(second.container);
      // now you can easily add additional lines
  }
  ```

  I'd also recommend keeping this consistent throughout the code.  You already use it some places (with the multi-line functions), but this should also be done with the single-line functions.
- For statements like these:

  ```
  threevector& operator-=(const threevector& rhs) 
  {
      *this += -rhs;
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  you can make it a single line:

  ```
  threevector& operator-=(const threevector& rhs) 
  {
      return *this += -rhs;
  }
  ```
- I'd use some parenthesis in the scalar product for clarity:

  ```
  {
      return (lhs[0] * rhs[0]) + (lhs[1] * rhs[1]) + (lhs[2] * rhs[2]);
  }
  ```